# Reset and redo https certificate using letsencrypt

Tags: linux, https, ssl-certificate

I'm following linuxbabe's tutorial* to set up my server and managed to screw up something and can't make https do it's job. The site can be reached via port 80, but not via port 443. Firefox says Unable to load.
Probably clearing all Apache-related ssl stuff would do it for a new beginning (but email certificates must not be touched! Those work as expected).
My question is, how can it be done in a safe manner?
Thank you!

PS: running Raspberry OS with Apache 2.4.52 and certbot.

- https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/postfixadmin-create-virtual-mailboxes-debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command "certbot delete".
It will list available certificates and you can chose which to delete.
After that, you redo the certification process.

PS: and don't forget to open port 443!
That was the reason I screwed things up.